# OpenMDAO: How to handle non-converging points in ExplicitComponent.compute?

Tags: openmdao

I've tried to handle non-converging points in the `compute` method of my `ExplicitComponent`, by raising an `AnalysisError`, as suggested in [What is the best way to tell openMDAO driver or solver that it is impossible to evaluate the model at some point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649921/what-is-the-best-way-to-tell-openmdao-driver-or-solver-that-it-is-impossible-to) (originally I wanted to make a comment in this thread, but I wasn't allowed due to my low Stack Overflow reputation score). However, this doesn't seem to solve my problem. What I expected was that error would be caught, the design point would be skipped and that the optimizer would continue to evaluate other points in order to find a solution. It is correct that the error is caught, but for some reason, the error is then reraised in `ScipyOptimizeDriver.run`. What is the purpose of this?

This is an example script for reproducing the behaviour:

```
import numpy as np
from openmdao.api import Problem, Group, IndepVarComp, ExplicitComponent, ScipyOptimizeDriver, ScipyKrylov, AnalysisError


class Test1Comp(ExplicitComponent):

    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('design_x', 1.0)
        self.add_input('design_y', 1.0)
        self.add_input('design_z', 0.5)
        self.add_output('y', val=0.1)
        self.add_output('z', val=0.1)
        self.add_output('obj', val=0.0)

        self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*', method='fd', form='central', step=1.0e-4)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        design_z = inputs['design_z']
        design_x = inputs['design_x']
        design_y = inputs['design_y']

        # Let's assume we have a model that has problems converging around design_x = 5.0
        if 0.49999 < design_x < 0.500001:
            raise AnalysisError()

        z = 4/(design_z + 1)
        y = - design_z - 2*z
        obj = (y/5.833333 - design_x)**2 + z/2.666667*100*(design_y - design_x**2)**2

        outputs["z"] = z
        outputs["y"] = y
        outputs['obj'] = obj


if __name__ == "__main__":

    prob = Problem()
    model = prob.model = Group()

    model.add_subsystem('d1', IndepVarComp('design_x', 1.0))
    model.add_subsystem('d2', IndepVarComp('design_y', 1.0))
    model.add_subsystem('d3', IndepVarComp('design_z', 0.5))
    model.add_subsystem('comp', Test1Comp())

    model.connect('d1.design_x', 'comp.design_x')
    model.connect('d2.design_y', 'comp.design_y')
    model.connect('d3.design_z', 'comp.design_z')

    prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver()
    prob.driver.options["optimizer"] = 'SLSQP'
    prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-8
    model.add_design_var("d1.design_x", lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
    model.add_design_var("d2.design_y", lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
    model.add_design_var("d3.design_z", lower=0.0, upper=1.0)
    model.add_objective('comp.obj')

    model.linear_solver = ScipyKrylov()
    model.linear_solver.options['maxiter'] = int(1200)
    model.linear_solver.options['restart'] = int(20)

    # prob.model.approx_totals()
    prob.setup()
    prob.run_driver()
    print(prob['comp.y'])
    print(prob['comp.z'])
```

Futrthermore, when looking at `ExplicitComponent._solve_nonlinear`, which is the method calling `ExplicitComponent.compute`, it appears to me that the natural way of communicating to OpenMDAO that a point is not converging would be to have `ExplicitComponent.compute` return `True`. See the source code for the method:

```
def _solve_nonlinear(self):
    """
    Compute outputs. The model is assumed to be in a scaled state.

    Returns
    -------
    boolean
        Failure flag; True if failed to converge, False is successful.
    float
        absolute error.
    float
        relative error.
    """
    super(ExplicitComponent, self)._solve_nonlinear()

    with Recording(self.pathname + '._solve_nonlinear', self.iter_count, self):
        with self._unscaled_context(
                outputs=[self._outputs], residuals=[self._residuals]):
            self._residuals.set_const(0.0)
            failed = self.compute(self._inputs, self._outputs)
    return bool(failed), 0., 0.
```

In summary, could someone clarify what is the recommended way of handling non-converging computations in `ExplicitComponent.compute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at your code, and you specified everything the correct way for telling an optimizer that the component could not evaluate the design point. The problem is that scipy.minimize (which is the optimizer underneath the`ScipyOptimizeDriver`) does not know what do do when it hits a failed point (other than raising an exception), and has no way to report a failure back (at least to my knowledge).

However, `pyOptSparseDriver` can do something when a point fails: it an try progressing again in the gradient direction, but with a smaller stepsize. I took your code, and exchanged the `ScipyOptimizeDriver` with a `pyOptSparseDriver`, used the "SLSQP" optimizer in that package, and it worked around that problematic point just fine, reaching what I assume is a good optimum:

```
[0.69651727]
[-5.]
[2.]
```

My driver option code looks like this:

```
prob.driver = pyOptSparseDriver()
prob.driver.options["optimizer"] = 'SLSQP'
prob.driver.opt_settings['ACC'] = 1e-8
```

If you don't already have pyoptsparse, which is a separate package not maintained by us, you can get it from https://github.com/mdolab/pyoptsparse -- and you can build and install it with:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

For your other question, I looked around through our code and found that the failure flag return on `_solve_nonlinear` is never used for anything. So, the only way to communicate a non-converging status to a driver or a higher-level solver is to raise the AnalysisError. Solvers canraise an AE when they don't converge, if "err_on_maxiter" on its options is set to True (the default is False).

As a final note, I think that while our error handling mechanisms are being used, we haven't thought of everything and are always open to suggestions for improvements.

Comment: You talk about "retrying failed points", which makes me wonder if we've misunderstood each other. What I'm after is simply what's raised in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649921/what-is-the-best-way-to-tell-openmdao-driver-or-solver-that-it-is-impossible-to: I want to tell the driver/solver that this point not only *did not converge*, but also *will not converge* and so the driver/solver should continue by evaluating the component for other points than this one. What do you mean with retrying a point?

Comment: I meant exactly what you said here: the driver or solver sees that the point failed, and it responds accordingly, usually by taking a smaller step in the line search direction. I will reword to make it clearer.

Comment: Also, could you please clarify your answer on the failure flag returned by `ExplicitComponent.compute`. You say that the flag is "mostly used by the nonlinear solvers when they fail to converge to tolerance". I'm not using any OpenMDAO nonlinear solver in my problem. What would be an example of a problem with a nonlinear solver using this failure flag to indicate convergence failure?

Comment: I dug a little deeper, and we never actually use the return flag from `_solver_nonlinear` to do anything. Reworded the above. Not entirely sure what we will do with this, but of the two ways to communicate non-convergence to a higher level, an exception is more efficient because it returns control immediately to whichever solver or driver is going to try to work around the non-convergent point.