# OpenMDAO: What are the pros and cons when comparing ScipyOptimizeDriver to pyOptSparseDriver?

Tags: openmdao

I learned in [OpenMDAO: How to handle non-converging points in ExplicitComponent.compute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50256104/openmdao-how-to-handle-non-converging-points-in-explicitcomponent-compute) that pyOptSparseDriver enables handling of failed points in a way that ScipyOptimizeDriver doesn't. I also understand that the available optimization methods differ. What are other important differences between these two drivers?

In particular, what are the differences when using the "SLSQP" optimizer in each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not quantified the detailed implementation differences between SLSQP in scipy and pyopt-sparse. However, I know they do differ a bit. The Scipy optimizer's line search is better about respecting bound-constraints than pyopt-spars's version of it.

The main difference is that the ScipyOptimizerDriver works with the pre-compiled optimizers in SciPy. On the other hand, you have to compile pyopt-sparse yourself.